# Fast update of 50 thousand records in DB2

Tags: db2

I need to execute more than 50 thousand update queries in DB2 and its taking 3 hours to execute only 1500 records. Below is the sample update query , this table has index however it still takes a lot of time. I would like to know whether there is any other to speed up the execution time. The unique index is on ITEEMNUM and ITEMSETID . Each update statement updates 1 row only.

```
UPDATE DEMO SET CXDEMO=(select orgid from organization where itemsetid = 'ABC') 
 WHERE ITEMNUM='0039523-03' AND itemsetid='ABC';
 UPDATE DEMO  SET CXDEMO=(select orgid from organization where itemsetid = 'ABC') 
 WHERE ITEMNUM='0039523-07' AND itemsetid='ABC';
 UPDATEDEMO  SET CXDEMO=(select orgid from organization where itemsetid = 'ABC') 
 WHERE ITEMNUM='0039528-03' AND itemsetid='ABC';
```

Comment: On what column(s) are the indexes? What is the explain plan? What type of disk and bufferpool setup? Is a statement per transaction or how many statements are part of a transaction? Please add details

Comment: @data_henrik I'm not sure how to figure out the disk and bufferpool setup. I have updated the other details.

Comment: @max092012 It’s probably possible to use a single UPDATE statement, but you need to explain why you use so strange update method with 50k updates with constants, how you got such a huge number of update statement. This may help to construct more efficient solution.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein There is a table with 100K records and each record has unique ITEMNUM. These items should be updated with a value in CXDEMO column. I prepared the update statement like the sample query added  in my question.

Comment: @max092012 Is this some strange educational demo or do you need to build a solution for real life? If latter, then why didn’t you prepare, let’s say, a table with these 50k constants instead to run a single update statement afterwards? If former, then show an access plan of any update statement from the `db2exfmt` utility.

Comment: Can you share what version of Db2 and which platform?

Comment: I will probably reconstruct my query since this is a data cleansing activity.